# RegEx/Python: optional whitespace not found

Tags: python, regex

got a really weird problem. My (Python) RegEx looks like this:

```
u'^.*(?:Grundfl|gfl|wfl|wohnfl|whg|wohnung).*(\s\d{1,3}[.,]?\d{1,2}?)\s*(?:m\u00B2|qm)'
```

In a re.findall()-term, this should throw two matches in for the following text: "...from 71m² to 83m²"
However, only 83 is matched. The problem has something to do with the optional whitespace between the number (\s\d{1,3}[.,]?\d{1,2}?) and the squaremeters (?:m\u00B2|qm), for when I'm deleting the \s*, only 71 is matched as expected. I have no idea what is wrong with my regex.
Thanks for yout help!

Comment: The question is somewhat unclear: do you want to get the first number? Then try [`^.*(?:Grundfl|gfl|wfl|wohnfl|whg|wohnung).*?\s(\d{1,3}[.,]?\d{1,2}?)\s*(?:m\u00B2|qm)`](https://regex101.com/r/iU2iV0/1). You will not get two matches because the pattern is anchored at the start of a string with `^`. So, also try [`^.*?(?:Grundfl|gfl|wfl|wohnfl|whg|wohnung).*?\s(\d{1,3}[.,]?\d{1,2}?)\s*(?:m\u00B2|qm)(?:\s+to\s+(\d{1,3}[.,]?\d{1,2}?)\s*(?:m\u00B2|qm))?`](https://regex101.com/r/iU2iV0/3). Or just a simple [`(\d{1,3}[.,]?\d{1,2}?)\s*(?:m\u00B2|qm)`](https://regex101.com/r/iU2iV0/4)

Comment: I can't reproduce this - removing the `\s*` doesn't change the match: https://regex101.com/r/mO1rH2/1 - but aside from that, `\d{1,2}?` doesn't mean "match 1 or 2 digits, optionally" - if anything, you need `\d{0,2}`.

Comment: Couldn't it be simplified altogether: [`(\d{1,2})\D+(\d{1,2})`](https://regex101.com/r/mO1rH2/2) ?

Comment: What is the Python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try using a positive lookahead? This will match 1+ digits (with an optional comma inside), as long as there is `m²` or `qm` after it. There is an optional space between the numbers and the unit:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("[\d|\,]{1,}(?=\s{0,4}[m\u00B2|qm])", "from 71m² to 83m²")
['71', '83']
>>> re.findall("[\d|\,]{1,}(?=\s{0,4}[m\u00B2|qm])", "from 71,56 m² to 837,78 qm")
['71,56', '837,78']
>>>
```

It does not take into account the words you have specified, but you can easily add that part back in. However re.findall() returns **non-overlapping** results, so if you specify the start of the string in your search, it will only ever return the first value, as it effectively 'chops' out parts that it matches, therefore never finding the second part.

Comment: Aha, so, there can't be `100m²` in the input string? Why accept this answer if it does not account for floats or all integers?

Comment: There is no point in using a lookahead as you can use a capturing group with `re.findall`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you elaborate? The lookahead is so it only matches numbers that have the units after, otherwise any random digits in the string will return a match..

Comment: No, you will get the same results using  `\d(?=m)` and `(\d)m` with `re.findall`. Now, your `"\d{1,}(?=\s{0,1}[m\u00B2|qm])"` regex is just incorrect.

Comment: You confuse character classes with grouping constructs. Besides, it is a bad idea to use regular and not raw string literals to declare regex patterns in Python (prone with errors later). Moreover, the question is not about matching overlapping texts, the lookaheads are redundant structures here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex with `re.findall`:

```
(\d*[.,]?\d+)\s*(?:m\u00B2|qm)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF8zN8/1). `re.findall` will only return a list of Group 1 captured values.

Pattern details:

- `(\d*[.,]?\d+)` - Group 1 containing the integer or float number: 0+ digits, followed with 1 or 0 `.` or `,` followed with 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:m\u00B2|qm)` - either `m²` or `qm`.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/OA9ijN):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
p = re.compile(u'(\d*[.,]?\d+)\s*(?:m\u00B2|qm)')
s = u"wohnung from 71,556m² to 183.4456m²"
print(p.findall(s)) # => [u'71,556', u'183.4456']
```